# Reshaping Pandas Data Frame by Index with Duplicate Indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame similar to this:

```
questions = ['What color?', 'What day?', 'How cold?', 'What color?', 'What color?']
answers = ['red', 'tuesday', '45', 'blue', 'red']
ids = [0, 1, 2, 3, 0]
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0, 1, 2, 0, 0], 'questions': questions, 'answers': answers})

 >>> id questions    answers
      0  What color? red
      1  What day?   tuesday
      2  How cold?   45
      0 What color?  blue
      0 What color?  red
```

I want this:

```
     How cold? What color?  What day?
id          
0       None    red          None
2       None    None         tuesday
3       45      None         None
4       None    blue         None
0       None    red          None
```

I have tried:

```
df.pivot(values='answers', index='id', columns='questions')
```

However, pivot always results in an error due to duplicates in the index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve that using [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) method :

```
df.pivot(columns="questions",values="answers")
```

output

```
    How cold?   What color? What day?
0   NaN          red         NaN
1   NaN          NaN     tuesday
2   45           NaN         NaN
3   NaN         blue         NaN
4   NaN         red          NaN
```

EDIT if you want to keep the indexes you had, you can do :

```
new_df = df.pivot(columns="questions",values="answers")
new_df.index = df.index
```

Answer (score 3):

If duplicates you need:

```
df['g'] = df.groupby('id').cumcount()
df = df.set_index(['id','g', 'questions']).unstack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
print (df)
questions How cold? What color? What day?
id                                       
0              None         red      None
0              None        blue      None
0              None         red      None
1              None        None   tuesday
2                45        None      None
```